# If you catch COVID-19, do you need to be vaccinated after recovery?

Tags: coronavirus, vaccination, covid

When we catch a cold, influenza, or COVID-19, the body starts to produce antibodies against them, so the body becomes immune for a period of time. That means one should not catch them again whilst there is the presence of immunity. Being vaccinated during this period of time seems to be useless.

Imagine someone caught COVID-19 one month ago, should they get vaccinated later?

Comment: I don't think the question is suitable under the community rules. Having said that - indeed, in most affected countries vaccination is recommended only a few months after teh recovery from COVID-19. Moreover, as teh sanitary measures go, the certificate of recovery from COVID-19 is usually accepted as an equivalent of the vaccination certificate.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a medical question, more suitable for SE Medical Sciences.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Studies on reinfections consistently show that a booster vaccination after an infection further reduces the risk of contracting COVID-19 a second time. The recommended time interval is 6 month after the infection.

A vaccination also can reduce the symptoms of Long Covid although the mechanism of this effect is not yet known.

Comment: To which studies do you refer?